# Send huge (approx 40K bytes) data through UDP protocol, how it was possible?

Tags: c, udp, embedded, ethernet, ipv4

I am working on Ethernet module, in which I am using IPv4 and UDP to transmit data over Ethernet.

I know, as per theory Ethernet can transmit 65K bytes of data.
But in single frame as per MTU, we can transmit only 1518 bytes(approx) of data including header, addresses.

After 1518 bytes of data, Is Ethernet module will take care of transfer for remaining data or the programmer need to write any logic for that.

In Internet i found that large data can be fragmented using IP fragmentation.

So the fragmentation procedure stack is provided by vendor or not?

Is vendor have their won Ethernet stacks to transfer huge data?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: note that noone can answer the part about where you can find `UDP_Send()` code until you tell us what you're working on. What library/platform/compiler/SDK etc. are you using that contains an `UDP_Send()` function ?

Comment: dont bother with fragmentation, that is evil.  just break the data into smaller chunks and send each. add a header to order them.  If you have to fragment then do that yourself, build each fragment and send it out.  30+ year old rfcs explain it all...

Comment: i am using a free scale controller, what i am asking you is the free scale vendor will provide any library or Stack to take care of all these fragmentation and transfer.
Coming to UDP_Send() function, in some Ready made API's i found that function.

Answer (score 1):

Your application can transmit the entire payload of approx. 40K bytes as a single UDP message. This is because, internally, the IP protocol can fragment and re-assemble datagrams of up to 64KBytes for their transmission into smaller packets. Since your payload is under this limit, and IP datagram can carry your intended payload.

As the MTU in ethernet is 1518 bytes, the IP stack will fragment the message into multiple IP packets at the sending side. On receiving side, the IP stack will re-assemble the IP fragments into single IP packet having 40K bytes payload. The application on the receiving side would be able to read the 40Kbytes message only after IP stack successfully reassembles the message.

You can refer to Linux kernel UDP code at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/udp.c.

The explanation of an IP datagram and how it can tag sub-packets for re-assembly can be found here: http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/Course/Section3/7.htm

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

But here i am using the firmware board, which don't have any OS as you know that.
In this situation , Is the Controller vendor will give any API or Library or the vendor will provide any Related Stack or Is the programmer need to develop any logic for fragmentation of data.

Comment: The IP stack is responsible for fragmenting the data